# Is there a way to require a particular value as a parameter in an abstract Interface method in Java?

Tags: java, oop, preconditions

I'm writing a little functional Interface and the method that it contains, takes an int as parameter. I was wondering if there's any way to check that when this method will be called, the value passed to the method, will not exceed a certain value and if it does, throw an error. Is there maybe an annotation I can add?

This is what my interface looks like

```
public interface DrawCardHandler{
    void onDrawCard(int slot);
}
```

Comment: You could try something like [Design by Contract](https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/september-2011-design-by-contract-in-java-with-google).  Otherwise, no; you would have to build that kind of validation into the implementation.

Comment: As an aside, that implementation looks like one of the few places where Java handily beats C#.  AFAICT Microsoft never could get their implementation of Code Contracts to work properly, and this Java implementation looks awesome.

Comment: If all you want to do is "throw an error," you can just write `if (slot > maxValue) { throw new IllegalArgumentException(...); }`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman but where would it be possible to write this code? It doesn't seem possible to me to add it to the method while keeping it abstract

Comment: Depending on the solution you want to build it may be an option to replace int with a custom type that only may values from a sub range of int. Or maybe even an enum.

Comment: You can't add it to the interface, no.  Only to the implementations.  You can document that implementations should do the check, but there's nothing you can do to enforce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Define a class

Rather than pass around a mere `int` primitive, define a class to represent your specific meaning.

```
public final class Slot {
    private int value;
    public Slot(int value) {  // Constructor.
        if(/** your check goes here **/) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        }
        this.value = value;
     }
     // getter etc. goes here.
}
```

In Java 16 and later, use the [records](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature. A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to communicate data transparently and immutably. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`. We can choose to write an explicit constructor to validate the input.

```java
public record Slot (int value) {
    public Slot(int value) {  // Constructor.
        if(/** your check goes here **/) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        }
        this.value = value;
    }
    // The getters, equals & hashCode, and toString are implicitly created by compiler.
}
```

Then your interface could look like:

```
public interface DrawCardHandler{
    void onDrawCard(Slot slot);
}
```

## Define an enum

In general, if you know all possible slots in advance, you can create an enum for `Slot` instead of a class like I've shown - it will be even more expressive.

Comment: Yep.  That's pretty much stock standard validation.

Comment: For the `record` solution, given you are only doing validation in the constructor I would suggest a compact constructor. You can remove the method arguments and the explicit `this.value = value` assignment and just have the validation code. See https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/records-come-to-java#anchor_7